# how to bind sharepoint online list with HTML table using Jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, data-binding

Can someone please tell me how can I bind SharePoint online list data with HTML table.
I can read SharePoint data using CamlQuery , but don't know how to bind it to HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand. Do you mean you want to grab the data from a Sharepoint list and then inject it into your page as a HTML table?
If yes, using [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) you could do something like that:

```
$SP().list("Name of your list").get({fields:"Field1,Field2"}, function(data) {
  // start building the code for your HTML table
  var html = '<table><thead><tr><th>Column 1</th><th>column 2</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
  // build each row
  for (var i=data.length; i--;) html += '<tr><td>'+data[i].getAttribute("Field1")+'</td><td>'+data[i].getAttribute("Field2")+'</td></tr>'
  html += '</tbody></table>'
  // now you can inject it somewhere into your page
  $('body').append(html)
})
```